# Two nested for loops

Tags: python, python-2.7

I dont know how to properly ask this question but here is what I am trying to do.

```
lists = []
for x in range(3):
  for y in range(3):
    if x!=y:
      lists.append([x,y])
```

Is there a simple solution so it doesnt give me lists that are the same but reversed:
for example [2,0] and [0,2]?

I know I could go through the lists and remove them afterwards but is there a solution to not even make the list? (sorry my english isnt perfect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations(range(3), 2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

With the above example we take any combination of two elements from `range(3)` without repeating any elements.

Comment: nice, thank you! sorry if it was asked before, I didnt know how to search for it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Sure: if you add all pairs with `y > x` instead of all possible pairs, only one of each pair (x, y) and (y, x) will appear.

```
lists = []
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(x + 1, 3):
        lists.append([x,y])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want those "duplicates", you want a *[combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)*

> a combination is a way of selecting items from a collection, such that (unlike permutations) the order of selection does not matter

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations(iterable=range(3), r=2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Above I have used [combinations()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from the Python module [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

### Explanation

- I've set `r=2` because you want a *subsequence length* of 2 (the form you described as `[x, y]`)
- The `iterable=range(3)` parameter is just a list of elements that are going to be used to make combinations of, so `range(3)` would result in `[0, 1, 2]`
- The `list()` applied to the end result is simply to force the output to be printed out to the console because otherwise `itertools.combinations` returns an iterable that you iterate through to pull the elements one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
for x in range(3):
  for y in range(x, 3):
      lists.append([x,y])
```